# ImportError: cannot import name 'app' with Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I have an issue with the configuration of `Flask-Mail`.

Here is my directory structure:

```
▾ app/
  ▾ controllers/
      __init__.py
      mail.py
▾ config/
    __init__.py
▾ run.py
```

In my run.py i have:

```
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The config is in `config/__init__.py`

```
import os
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'my precious'
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
MAIL_SERVER = 'ssl0.foo.net'
MAIL_PORT = 465
MAIL_USE_SSL = True
MAIL_USERNAME = 'contact@foo.bar'
MAIL_PASSWORD = 'EwCa2kd'
```

The config is loaded in the `app/__init__.py`

```
import logging

from flask import Flask
from app.controllers import pages
from flask_mail import Mail

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.development')

app.register_blueprint(pages.blueprint)

app.logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
mail = Mail(app)
```

And I would like to create a mail controller in `controllers/mail.py` with

```
from flask_mail import Message
from .. import app, mail

def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body):
    msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    msg.html = html_body
    mail.send(msg)
```

But i can not use `mail` in this controller, i tried several combinations but i got some import error like : `ImportError: cannot import name 'app'`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is current_app. It can be imported as:

```
from flask import current_app
```

Read http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.current_app for more info.

Then use:

```
with current_app.app_context():
    # mail sending logic goes here
```